# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "dBname"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, visual-studio, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

I was trying to create a table in PostgreSQL and when I type the following code, I get the error as:

> **psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "dBname"**

Code:

```py
def create():
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dBname='database1'  user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost' 
    port='5432'")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store(item TEXT,quantity INTEGER,price REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Terminal:
**psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "dBname"**

Comment: `dBname` should be `dbname` in  `psycopg2.connect("dBname='database1' `

Answer (score 0):

```
conn=psycopg2.connect("dBname=database1  user=postgres password=postgres host=localhost")
```